# Installing c-wire adapter on hvac

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I'm installing an Amazon smart thermostat.
The hvac control board has 3 of the wires that the instructions state to disconnect and connect to the adapter (G, W, Y). But it's missing R, and Y has two wires connected and only one of them is grouped with the other connected wires which im assuming all 3 of those grouped wires go to the thermostat. The other wire connected to Y is red and it looks like it connects to a black wire and goes off towards the ac unit. To complicate it more, there's a red wire that comes out of the group 3 wired and it goes off toward the ac unit as well. I've attached a before and after pic of my adapter install but, after turning the breaker back on, the thermostat doesn't power on. Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: sorry, I can not understand what you wrote. maybe try to draw a schematic